# Why is the error "Not a valid command: assembly-merge-strategy"?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have the following `build.sbt` file.

```
import AssemblyKeys._

name := "approxstrmatch"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies+="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0"

resolvers += "AkkaRepository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"

// My merge strategy is specified here.

lazy val app = Project("approxstrmatch", file("approxstrmatch"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ assemblySettings ++ Seq(
    mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
    {
        case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("javax", "transaction", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("javax", "mail", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
        case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
        case "unwanted.txt"     => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => old(x)
        }
    })
  )

mainClass in assembly := Some("approxstrmatch.JaccardScore")
// jarName in assembly := "approstrmatch.jar"
```

When I execute the following command `sbt assembly-merge-strategy` there's an error I don't understand. Any help appreciated.

```
approxstrmatch]$ sbt assembly-merge-strategy
[info] Loading project definition from /apps/sameert/software/approxstrmatch/project
[info] Set current project to approxstrmatch (in buildfile:/apps/sameert/software/approxstrmatch/)
[error] Not a valid command: assembly-merge-strategy
[error] No such setting/task
```

Comment: What's your `project/plugins.sbt`? I suspect you use sbt-assembly, and need your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding tells me there's no `assembly-merge-strategy` task in [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin (I can only suspect you use that plugin in your build).

Execute `assembly` as described in https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#assembly-task as *"an awesome new assembly task which will compile your project, run your tests, and then pack your class files and all your dependencies into a single JAR file"*.

Comment: There's a setting key named `assembly-merge-strategy` - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/5657dacd0325fc7606ace12adadbdcfea22d2d0c/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/Plugin.scala#L26

Comment: That's correct, but the OP said *"When I execute the following command sbt assembly-merge-strategy"* and hence the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting named `assemblyMergeStrategy` (aka `assembly-merge-strategy`). It's just that you won't directly use it. The way sbt-assembly uses it is scoped to `assembly` task:

```scala
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= ....
```

So here's what you have to do to call it from the shell:

```
$ sbt assembly::assemblyMergeStrategy
[info] blabla other things...
[info] <function1>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `assemblySettings` in your build.sbt will help